# How to Make FlyOutMenu so it slides from the right?

Tags: android, android-layout

1. I'm trying to make sliding menu from Right side on button Click.but
   in  the given code it's slide from Left i change in Several method
   and values but i wont get the result as i want.
2. I tired but Don't know where should i Change??

Help me to figure this out.

```
FlyOutContainer.java

package com.dell.myflyoutmenu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Scroller;

public class FlyOutContainer extends LinearLayout {
    // References to groups contained in this view.
    private View menu;
    private View content;
    // Layout Constants
    protected static final int menuMargin = 150;
    public enum MenuState {
        CLOSED, OPEN, CLOSING, OPENING
    };
    // Position information attributes
    protected int currentContentOffset = 0;
    protected MenuState menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;
    // Animation objects
//    protected Scroller menuAnimationScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
//            new LinearInterpolator());
    protected Scroller menuAnimationScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
new SmoothInterpolator());
    protected Runnable menuAnimationRunnable = new AnimationRunnable();
    protected Handler menuAnimationHandler = new Handler();
    // Animation constants
    private static final int menuAnimationDuration = 1000;
    private static final int menuAnimationPollingInterval = 16;
    public FlyOutContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    public FlyOutContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public FlyOutContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.menu = this.getChildAt(0);
        this.content = this.getChildAt(1);
        this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
                            int bottom) {
        if (changed)
            this.calculateChildDimensions();
        this.menu.layout(left, top, right - menuMargin, bottom);
        this.content.layout(left + this.currentContentOffset, top, right
                + this.currentContentOffset, bottom);
    }
    public void toggleMenu() {
        switch (this.menuCurrentState) {
            case CLOSED:
                this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPENING;
                this.menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.menuAnimationScroller.startScroll(0, 0, this.getMenuWidth(),
                0, menuAnimationDuration);
                break;
            case OPEN:
                this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSING;
                this.menuAnimationScroller.startScroll(this.currentContentOffset,
                        0, -this.currentContentOffset, 0, menuAnimationDuration);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        this.menuAnimationHandler.postDelayed(this.menuAnimationRunnable,
                menuAnimationPollingInterval);
        this.invalidate();
    }
    private int getMenuWidth() {
        return this.menu.getLayoutParams().width;
    }
    private void calculateChildDimensions() {
        this.content.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
        this.content.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth();
        this.menu.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth() - menuMargin;
        this.menu.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
    }
    private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isAnimationOngoing) {
        int scrollerOffset = this.menuAnimationScroller.getCurrX();
        this.content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerOffset
                - this.currentContentOffset);

        this.currentContentOffset = scrollerOffset;
        this.invalidate();
        if (isAnimationOngoing)
            this.menuAnimationHandler.postDelayed(this.menuAnimationRunnable,
                    menuAnimationPollingInterval);
        else
            this.onMenuTransitionComplete();
    }
    private void onMenuTransitionComplete() {
        switch (this.menuCurrentState) {
            case OPENING:
                this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPEN;
                break;
            case CLOSING:
                this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;
                this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
    protected class SmoothInterpolator implements Interpolator{
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float t) {
            return (float)Math.pow(t-1, 5) + 1;
        }
    }
    protected class AnimationRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FlyOutContainer.this
                    .adjustContentPosition(FlyOutContainer.this.menuAnimationScroller
                            .computeScrollOffset());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code made by Jay Lamont https://github.com/jaylamont/AndroidFlyOutMenuDemo/tree/part2

Comment: is Here nobody how understand this Code ?????????